# How to add custom css/js files to a template in wordpress

Tags: themes, page-template

I know this question has been asked many times but my requirements is bit different. Actually i want to add custom css/js to a particular template.
First i show you my folder structure - 
[image]
I do have a *TradePartners* folder on root which further contains *css/js* files inside *css/js* folder. Moreover this(TradePartners) folder contains a *trade.partners.php* file where i want to add these two css/js file but whenever i put css code inside css file it throws away css code at the top of whole site and js also does not work.
Now i send you php code.

[image]

So now can please someone let me know how to add these files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your **becomeTradePartner** function as static.

So try the following method to call it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'TradePartner::becomeTradePartner' );
```

Comment: But why to call _becomeTradePartners_ function because it is already inside the class constructor so as soon as i will create the object of the class, which i have done at the bottom(not visible in screenshot), this function will be called automatically.
Moreover, as long as i know _static_ keyword does not affect in this case because i am not calling this function inside or outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

With static functions, you can add the action with `__CLASS__` instead of `$this`:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [__CLASS__, 'becomeTradePartner']);`

Comment: But why to call becomeTradePartners function because it is already inside the class constructor so as soon as i will create the object of the class, which i have done at the bottom(not visible in screenshot), this function will be called automatically. Moreover, as long as i know static keyword does not affect in this case because i am not calling this function inside or outside the class

Comment: the add_action line for 'wp_enqueue_scripts' indeed is inside the constructor. But the function which is called for that hook is becomeTradePartner. From the codex:  
`add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )`  

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/  

That callable function for a function within the class is as we've already specified.